# tkinter python 3 using canvas.insert() to display output from function

Tags: python, canvas, interface, widget, tkinter

I was wondering if/how I can use canvas.insert() to display the results of a function I wrote. Basically, the function is an interactive text-search and I want to display the string output.

The following code is what I have come up with, but I dont know how to call the text-search function so that its result (string output) pops up in a window.

I am using PyCharm with python 3.

Thanks in advance!

```
from tkinter import *

canvas_width = 600
canvas_height = 300

colours = ("#476042", "yellow")
box=[]

for ratio in ( 0.2, 0.35 ):
box.append( (canvas_width * ratio,
            canvas_height * ratio,
            canvas_width * (1 - ratio),
            canvas_height * (1 - ratio) ) )

master = Tk()

w = Canvas(master,
       width=canvas_width,
       height=canvas_height)
w.pack()


canvas.insert(w, tk.END, <results of text-scan function>)  ''' this is where I get stuck

mainloop()
```

Comment: where's the text-search func?

Comment: Where is `mainloop` defined?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to use the canvas, when a Text widget seems like the natural choice for displaying strings?

Comment: I would be happy to use either. The output that I would like displayed would be dynamic, based on the function, so I am trying to figure out how to make the canvas/widget be able to call the function.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a text widget, if all you're doing is appending strings. The code would look something like this:

```
text_widget = Text(master)
...
results = <text scan function>
text_widget.insert("end", results)
```

If your results doesn't have a newline at the end, you'll want to add one so you get one result per line.